# Service 'web' failed to build: no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries

Tags: docker, docker-container

I wanted to build a containers by using this command: `docker-compose up --build`. But now I got an error message:

```
Building web
Step 1/5 : FROM nginx:1
1: Pulling from library/nginx
Service 'web' failed to build: no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

I tried to use `Linux containers` or set `--experimental: true` in the settings, but none of those solutions worked for me.

Could someone give any advices on how to fix it?

**Progress:**

If someone currently facing this issue, this might be a problem from nginx: [github](https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/262)

Comment: it's a Docker infra problem https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/issues/262

Comment: I'm using nodeJS and have the same problem. So its not nginx.